# Making shared pointer of template class using std::tuple<void> tries to form a reference to `void`

Tags: templates, c++17, shared-ptr, stdtuple

I have this simple snippet of code [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/nfMe714qY):

```
template <class V> inline constexpr bool IsVoidTuple_t = std::is_same_v<V, std::tuple<void>>;

template<typename Type>
class C {
public:
    using ResultOptionalType = std::conditional_t<IsVoidTuple_t<Type>, std::monostate, std::optional<Type>>;
};

int main() {
    using ResultOptionalType = std::conditional_t<IsVoidTuple_t<std::tuple<void>>, std::monostate, std::optional<std::tuple<void>>>;     // OK
    using T = std::optional<std::tuple<void>>;    // OK

    C<std::tuple<void>> c1;       // OK
    auto c2 = std::make_unique<C<std::tuple<void>>>();   // OK
    auto c3 = std::make_shared<C<std::tuple<void>>>();   // Error: forming reference to void
}
```

I'm not creating any explicit instance of `std::tuple<void>`, also because the code itself comes from the need to prevent such case at compile time in my codebase. However, I am getting error `forming reference to void` when creating the shared resource with `make_shared<T>` and I cannot understand why this happens.

The thing that makes me really confused is that in all the other cases that I listed inside the `main()` function I am able to compile without problems. The only difference that I might think it could cause the issue is the reference counting mechanism implemented by `shared_ptr`.

**TL;DR** I would expect the above code to compile for all the cases listed in the main function body. Still, it seems that with shared pointers there is an hidden instantiation of a `std::tuple<void>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dived into the [gcc's source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L1742-L1745), and found it fell into a pattern **like**

```
foo(p); // p is of type C<std::tuple<void>>*
```

Here, the compiler will instantiate `std::tuple<void>` due to ADL.

I'm unsure if this is a point that can be improved in the implementation of compilers. You can avoid it by using `std::tuple<std::type_identity<void>>` rather than `std::tuple<void>>`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vMMKdbqW3)